# How to perform multiple join dataframe in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, join, pyspark

I have multiple (4) spark dataframe (10 millions row in each one) 
I need to join this dataframes on multiple columns (4 columns)
Actually, I used the code below but it's very very slow

```
sql = SQLContext(sc)
df1 = sql.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").\
             load(keyspace="db", table="table1").\
             select('time','regionid','wilayaid','siteid','col1', 'col2','col3','col4','col5')
df2 = sql.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").\
             load(keyspace="db", table="table2").\
             select('time','regionid','wilayaid','siteid','col6', 'col7','col8','col9')
df3 = sql.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").\
             load(keyspace="db", table="table3").\
             select('time','regionid','wilayaid','siteid','col10')
df4 = sql.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").\
             load(keyspace="db", table="table4").\
             select('time','regionid','wilayaid','siteid','col12')
join1 = df1.join(edf2,['time','regionid','wilayaid','siteid'])
join2 = join1.join(df3,['time','regionid','wilayaid','siteid'])
join3 = join2.join(df4,['time','regionid','wilayaid','siteid'])
join3.show()
```

Any suggestion to perform this code